# If $a>1$, the number of values of $x$ for which $\log_a x=x=a^x$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

My book says $0$ solutions for $a>1$, but as $1<a<1.44 \text{ (approx)}$ that graphs intersect at two positions. So is the answer $2$ for $1<a<1.44$, and $0$ for $a>1.44$.

I'm not sure about the exact value of the upper limit of $a$. Could you please find out the exact value? (If it is a irrational number, is it possible to write in any known forms like root or logarithm?)

Comment: The exact value is $e^{1/e} \approx 1.4446678610097661337\cdots$. You can figure this out by asking when $y=x$ becomes a tangent line to $y=a^x$.

Comment: This may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2826160/for-what-number-n-does-the-equation-log-nx-nx-have-exactly-one-solutio